# Is my understanding of Kant's arguments for the categories correct?

Tags: kant

So from what I understand from my reading of the Critique of Pure Reason, specifically in the Transcendental Deduction, is that Kant states that in order to have a unified self-conscious (a unified "I") we must necessarily synthesize the small bits of intuition (the manifold of intuition) to have a synthesized apperception. The way in which we synthesize and unify the manifold is by the categories Is this an accurate presentation of the argument? Are there parts I'm missing?

If not, can we possibly critique this argument by denying that the unity of self-conscious is necessarily correlated with the unity of the manifold of intuition?

If this argument has holes, what are more consistent ways of critiquing Kant's argument in the transcendental deduction?

Comment: Just denying an argument is not, by itself, a critique.